# edit form: default value file field

Tags: 7

On my edit form I need to fill in the file field, this is my current code:

```
    $form['file'] = array( 
    '#title'        => t('Upload image'),
    '#type'         => 'file',
    '#description'  => t('Images must be one of jpg, bmp, gif or png formats.'),
    '#default_value'        => "$link->icon",
    '#ajax'         => array(
      'wrapper'       => 'box',
      'name'          => 'icon2',
    ),
);
```

but the file field remains empty, in this way the admin has to reselect the desired image each time he edits the entry. The field returns 'no file chosen'.

Any ideas?

**Update I**

```
$form['file'] = array( 
    '#title'        => t('Upload image'),
    '#type'         => 'managed_file',
    '#description'  => t('Images must be one of jpg, bmp, gif or png formats.'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('', $fid),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    '#ajax'         => array(
      'wrapper'       => 'box',
      'name'          => 'icon2',
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the FAPI documentation, `#default_value` isn't a valid property for a [file element](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#file) which is probably why adding it to the array has no effect.

You might have better luck using a [managed file element](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) instead; although the documentation also states that a `#default_value` is not valid for that type either, I've used it successfully for ages now. The default value needs to be a file id (`fid`) which references a file in the `file_managed` table.

Comment: kk thanks this will help me further! Will post solution

Comment: hello again Clive, Im getting closer. I can now show a default image, but thats only when I manually add a fid. So right now I need to get the fid that belongs to the entry. How can I do this? see my updated code above

Comment: my entry id is 81, but the fid in the file_managed table is 128.. I have no idea how to solve this. Maybe I can add the fid to the entries table, but then I have to know the fid before saving it..help appreciated :)

Comment: The file ID is available when then form's been submitted, so you could add a submit handler to the form and run `variable_set('my_variable', $form_state['values']['file']);` to save the id, then pick it up again with the same variable name in the form function

Comment: thanks again for your help clive, I've managed to solve this :)

Comment: drupal_write_record('file_managed', $file, 'fid');
  $fid = $file->fid;